# Incremento Automatico em models.py Django

Tags: python, django

Boa tarde,

Estou aprendendo agora Django estou com uma situação talvez simples mas que eu nao estou conseguindo resolver.

No meu models.py eu estou fazendo um cadastro de clientes e gostaria que quando a pessoa fizesse o cadastro, gerasse um numero automático tipo: 1001, 1002...

Tem como fazer isso?

meu `models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from djmoney.models.fields import MoneyField
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField


class NewAccount(models.Model):
    """
    Models to create a new account
    """
    GENDER_CHOICE = (
        ("M", "Male"),
        ("F", "Female"),
    )

    objects = None

    account_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    phone = PhoneNumberField()
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=30, blank=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICE)
    income = MoneyField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default_currency='GBP')
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
```

essa e minha `views.py`

```
def user_view(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()

        else:
            form = {
                "user_form": user_form,
            }

            return render(request, 'sign.html', form)

    user = UserForm()

    return render(request, 'sign.html', {
        'user_form': user
    })
```

e o `forms.py`

```
from django import forms
from phonenumber_field.widgets import PhoneNumberPrefixWidget
from bank.models import NewAccount


class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    objects = None

    class Meta:
        model = NewAccount
        widgets = {
            'password': forms.PasswordInput,
            'phone': PhoneNumberPrefixWidget(initial='GB'),
        }
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 0):

O ORM do Django cria automaticamente mantém o campo `id` como incremental.

Porém, caso você queira criar o seu próprio, sua definição do model está correta. No entanto, eu utilizaria o `BigAutoField` Veja abaixo:

```
class NewAccount(models.Model):
    account_id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
```

Já no `forms.py` opte por não utilizar `fields = "__all__"` uma vez que o `account_id` não fará parte do form. Defina os campos em uma lista.

Comment: Certo, fiz a alteração para o que falou, mais no meu caso eu precisava de outro campo alem do ID, que começasse em 100 e fosse auto incrementado conforme o cadastro